# Is there a google web api to call the interpolate function in geometry library

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a google web api to call the interpolate function in geometry library ,like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?path=.. if you want to call for elevation service api for example.
The only way I could find to call it was through javascript call ,google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate ?

Comment: See: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html "intermediate point"

Comment: Exactly what I needed ,thanks a million .That site is full of gems .

Comment: Im trying to accept accept your answer but how ?

Comment: It is a comment, you can't accept comments.  I have provided an answer from that link, you can [accept that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an algorithm to compute an intermediate point along a great circle route (AKA "line") on http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

From that page:

> **Intermediate point**
>
> An intermediate point at any fraction along the great circle path between two points can also be calculated.1
>
> Formula:  a = sin((1−f)⋅δ) / sin δ
>
> b = sin(f⋅δ) / sin δ
>
> x = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ cos λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos λ2
>
> y = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ sin λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin λ2
>
> z = a ⋅ sin φ1 + b ⋅ sin φ2
>
> φi = atan2(z, √x² + y²)
>
> λi = atan2(y, x)
>
> where f is fraction along great circle route (f=0 is point 1, f=1 is point 2), δ is the angular distance d/R between the two points.